# Как можно сделать сложные плейсхолдеры в js

Tags: javascript

**Всем привет!**

Как можно заменить в строке

```js
const str = "My name is {{user.name}} and I am {{user.age}} years old."
```

```
{{user.name}} на Bob
```

и

```
{{user.age}} на 59
```

Объект выглядит так:

```js
const data = {
  user: {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 59
  }
}
```

Также, как можно применить фильтры на эти плейсхолдеры, допустим есть функция lower

```js
function lower (input) {
  return input.toLowerCase()
}
```

Как я могу применить его в плейсхолдере, допустим, у меня строка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
const str = "My name is {{user.name | lower}} and I am {{user.age}} years old."
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `const str = \`My name is ${user.name.toLowerCase()} and I am ${user.age} years old.\``

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце, чтобы найти все все группы типа `{{ content }}` используются [регулярные выражения](https://www.exlab.net/files/tools/sheets/regexp/regexp.png)

```js
const replacer = (content) => {
  content = content.slice(2, -2).trim();
  console.log(content);
  // здесь будет "user.name | lower" в первом совпадении и "user.age" во втором
  
  
  return 123;
}
str = str.replace(/\{\{.+?\}\}/g, replacer);
```

Перевод строки user.name в реальное значение уже совсем другая тема с множеством решений. Если хотите можете использовать eval, на клиентской части это не так опасно